# What's the difference between `return;` and no return?

Tags: php, function, methods, return-value

Is there a difference between:

```
function someMethod( $someArg ) {
  // some code
  return;
}
```

and

```
function someMethod( $someArg ) {
  // some code
  // no return
}
```

Both have `NULL` as 'return value'. Is there a difference? Something PHP internally? Performance? Speed?

**edit**
I ask, because in Zend framework ([in this video](http://www.zend.com/en/webinar/PHP/70170000000bYYX-webinar-anonymous-functions-in-php-53-20110426.flv)) they use `return;` which seemed (seems) silly to me. However, you would think that the people behind Zend framework do know their PHP...

Comment: A new `noreturn` type is going to be introduced in `php-8.1`, thought you'd be interested. Check the [rfc here](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/noreturn_type).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

php code

```
<?php

function a() {
   echo 1;
   return;
}

function b() {
   echo 2;
}
```

generated bytecode

```
.FUNCTION a
        ECHO                     1
        RETURN                   NULL
        RETURN                   NULL
        HANDLE_EXCEPTION         
.END FUNCTION

.FUNCTION b
        ECHO                     2
        RETURN                   NULL
        HANDLE_EXCEPTION         
.END FUNCTION
```

so the explicit return statement generates one extra RETURN instruction. Otherwise there's no difference.

Comment: This is exactly what I meant. I'd say from this using `return;` is **not** better for performance, because it adds extra commands. If no `return;` is specified, there's a return specified internally anyway. Did I read that correctly?

Comment: @Rudie: no, it is not worse, because only the first `RETURN NULL` is executed. But even if it was, you wouldn't notice the difference. Don't optimize prematurely.

Comment: @Marcel That's why I didn't say it's worse, but "is not better for performance". I'm not looking to optimize, just curious. I hear that's good.

Comment: @Marcel - @stereofrog is correct the performance difference is so negligable as to be considered zero because the second return will not even be executed

Comment: The second return may not be executed, but extra parsing and such may be occurring. Just because something is tiny, does not mean you should ignore it. You cannot dogmatically call this premature optimization if you are simply following the practice (best practice???) of omitting unnecessary return statements.

Answer (score 11):

As far as I know there is no difference.

The empty `return;` is mainly there to break out from a if/else, while or for loop without returning anything.

Answer (score 5):

Functionally there's no difference but it's always nice to have an obvious point of exit in a function (the return).  Some schools of computer science hold tht all functions and methods should have precisely 1, and only 1, point of exit.

Should you need to add a return value in the future then there's an obvious point already picked out for you in the code if you include an empty return.

But like I said, from a functional point of view there's not much difference.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, no difference.

However, `return` will terminate the function, so you have the option to skip code after the `return` statement (that's its purpose).

In your example, it is personal preference if you like to see the `return` or not.

Further, in some languages like Perl, the last expression is "implicitly" the return value, so you don't even need to use "return".  (This won't work in other languages like C++, though.)

```
sub foo {
  return 12;
}

sub foo2 {
  12;  # same thing
}
```

Comment: I could be wrong as I'm foggy with perl syntax but foo and foo2 will not return the same value. foo returns a value of 12 where foo2 does not return anything

Comment: In Perl, the return value is that of the "last evaluated expression", so both would return the same thing.  (Weird, but that's Perl.  ;-)) http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Perl/Returns-and-Perl-Subroutines/2/

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a major difference, you can just use `return;` to break out of a function call early. They will both return `NULL` either way, it's strictly for workflow.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert but I would say that if there is a difference in negligible; one could argue that your using up bites by putting return; or return false; at the end of a function.

typically I use  return with something like

```
return true;
```

or

```
return $var;
```

and if i don't want to return anything or I want to return false I just don't use return

Comment: But `return;` and `return false;` are very different.

Comment: yes they are return will return null and return false; will return false; I don't see what your getting at though ?

Comment: You said: "and if i don't want to return anything or I want to return false I just don't use return". Well If you want to return false, you should return something: `false`.

Comment: yes but evaluating as boolean i.e. true or false  null is the same as false is it not ?

Comment: Yup, we all know it is. But I was looking for specifics in my answer. Doesn't really matter. We both know what we mean. Ocasionally return values `""`, `NULL` and `FALSE` will do very different things. Other times, they do exactly the same.

Comment: ok my point was simply that if you use return then your using it and therefore it may take up some processing time which would be negligible but that would rally be the only difference I see, and using return, will return something whereas not using return does not

Comment: I get it. I often use it like that too.

Answer (score 1):

In language such as PHP and Python there's no real difference. `return;` can be used to break out of the function prematurely.

However, there is a difference when the programming language of choice is C/C++, Java, C#, where no return signifies a `void`

Comment: But `return;` signifies a void too, doesn't it?

Comment: `null`, `undefined` or `None`. I might be wrong but I think there's a difference in C/C++

Comment: Right, sorry, I meant in C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as `return` is called, the function call is terminated. It acts like a break. So if your return is in the middle, it would gain some performance because the rest of the function isn't executed.

For the rest, it is often better (in a readability manner) to use an explicit return in stead of a implicit one. If you keep the return in the function, you will know that a call to that function might expect a return value.

Answer (score 0):

return will break/exit the function (think break as in switch/case)

```
function someMethod( $someArg ) {
    if(condition) {
        return; // will exit function
    }

    // could be more code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes like to use an "empty" `return` as the last statement of a function as a friendly reminder that the function is not expected to return any value.

```
class foo {
  var $name;

  public function bar($x) {
    $this->name = $x;
    return;
  }
}
```

In ADA you have `procedures` and `functions`. The first do not return any data, they just execute some statements. The functions can return data.

So an empty `return` would be like 'this is a procedure'.

Answer (score 0):

Very interestingly (I think), having a return type makes a lot of difference. Three kinds of returning `null` throw three different errors:

```
function foo() : string {
  // return nothing

  // TypeError exception: Return value of foo() must be of the type string, none returned
}

function foo() : string {
  return;

  // Fatal error: A function with return type must return a value
}

function foo() : string {
  return null;

  // TypeError exception: Return value of foo() must be of the type string, null returned
}
```

I would not have guessed that, since all errors are runtime and all return values are technically `null`.